# Restore oryginal value after validation fails - infragistics UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, validation, infragistics

I've set RegexpPattern property in Infragistics UltraWinGrid column and it works - when user edit cell and given input doesn't match regexp cell is cleared. I would like to restore previous ( before edit started) value of cell instead of make it blank. How can I do it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

Create event handler for grid's event: `CellDataError` - set event argument properties as in following sample:

```
private void _ultraGrid_ConfigList_CellDataError(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
     e.StayInEditMode = false;
     e.RaiseErrorEvent = false;
     e.RestoreOriginalValue = true;
}
```